# Importing a view into another view

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a main view set up on my monotouch app. I've designed a partial view that I want to import into it (it's set out in it's own XIB file) and for the controller class to be able to intercept the events generated by the partial view controls.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Views inside other Views, but you probably want a ViewController for your inner view as well.

That's called UIViewController nesting, and handled, since iOS 5, with `AddChildViewController(UIViewController innerVC)`. This only manage the lifecycle of the ViewController. You also have to add the inner View in your main View, like this.

```cs
//MainViewController.cs
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    var innerVC = new InnerViewController ();
    AddChildViewController (innerVC);

    innerVC.View.Frame = new RectangleF (20, 20, 100, 100);
    Add (innerVC.View);
}
```

Read more on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

Comment: Thanks - my problem here though is the actual importing it. For example on Android, I tell it to fetch the view, then inflate it. How do I tell iOS to do the same with the other view controller?